# [array]::Reverse() method not working on Get-Content return object

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am writing a script to install/uninstall a collection of software. Some of this software must be installed before others, and when uninstalling they need to go in reverse order. I am attempting to design this script to read a text file containing the paths to all of the .msi files. This way I can read them with Get-Content in appropriate order, then if they need to be uninstalled I can read the same file and just reverse the array.

I'm new to powershell, but it's my understanding that get-object returns an object of type [array]. [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) on Get-Content doesn't specify a return type but every discussion of Get-Content on stack overflow describes the output as an array.

### Here's the problem:

When I store the output of Get-Content to a variable `$data = Get-Content -Path "C:\my\data.txt"` then I print what's stored in $data `write-host $data` I get the expected output:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
etc...
```

***However***

When I try to reverse  `$data = [array]::Reverse($data)`. It returns `null`

When I manually create an array `$letters = @("a","b","c")` and reverse it `$letters = [array]::reverse($letters)` then the out put of `write-host $letters` is, as expected:

```
c
b
a
```

### Here's the question

Why is my call to `[array]::reverse($data)` returning null? instead of doing as I would expect in my latter example `[array]::reverse($letters)`?

**NOTE:** the only difference between those two examples is how I created the array. So either the return type of `get-content` is not an array, or their is something uniquely different about the returned array that I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[array]::reverse()` method does not output the array in reverse, it simply reverses it in place, so given:

```
$x = 'A','B','C'
[array]::reverse($x)
$x
```

That will output:

```
C
B
A
```

If you want to have a second variable that is a reverse of an existing array you can clone the array to the second variable, and then reverse the array contained in the second variable:

```
$x = 'A','B','C'
$y = $x.clone()
[array]::reverse($y)
```

At this point `$x` = 'A', 'B', 'C' while `$y` = 'C', 'B', 'A'.

Comment: This makes sense. I come from a background of programming in a lot of other languages and poweshell simply doesn't behave in the way I would expect in most languages. Once I try this out back at my PC I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would share that I was able to accomplish my goal using a different line of code.

`$data = ($data[($data.Length-1)..0])`

This reversed my Get-Content return object. But it doesn't answer my question why the reverse method returns null.

Comment: I think this is simply a case of misplaced expectations, or, at least, a method not behaving - for performance reasons - in a way one might find typical or convenient:  [`Array.Reverse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse) doesn't return _anything_ (in the C# view, the return type is [void](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/void)).  That assigning a method that doesn't return anything to a variable sets the variable to `$null` is just the magic of PowerShell.